# How to alternate between printing in console and printing in a text file

Tags: java, system, outputstream

My code requires the program to print an array of numbers in a text file.

So, during these periods, I want to change my output stream:

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("data.txt")));
```

So, how would I return to printing in the console?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Why do use `System.out.print` instead of passing a `PrintStream` to the code doing the printing and printing to the `PrintStream` passed instead? If that's not possible: store `System.out` to variable, change `System.out`, print something, set `System.out` to old value.

Answer (score 0):

This example can help you:

https://github.com/dreedyman/Rio/blob/master/rio-start/src/main/java/org/rioproject/start/LogManagementHelper.java#L45

```
    static void redirectIfNecessary() {
    /* If we have been exec'd by Rio (such as a service that has been declared to be forked,
     * stdout and stderr have already been redirected */
    if(System.getenv("RIO_EXEC")==null && System.console()==null) {
        redirectToLogger();
    }
}

static void redirectToLogger(){
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out){
        public void print(String s){
            stdOutLogger.info(s);
        }
    });
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(System.err){
        public void print(String s){
            stdErrLogger.error(s);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example might be helpful....

```
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
//          EditorConsole.systemOut.println("editor window activated");
          base.handleActivated(Editor.this);
//          mode.handleActivated(Editor.this);
          fileMenu.insert(base.getSketchbookMenu(), 2);
          fileMenu.insert(base.getRecentMenu(), 3);
//          fileMenu.insert(mode.getExamplesMenu(), 3);
          sketchMenu.insert(mode.getImportMenu(), 4);
          mode.insertToolbarRecentMenu();
        }

        // added for 1.0.5
        // http://dev.processing.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=1260
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
//          EditorConsole.systemErr.println("editor window deactivated");
//          mode.handleDeactivated(Editor.this);
          fileMenu.remove(base.getSketchbookMenu());
          fileMenu.remove(base.getRecentMenu());
//          fileMenu.remove(mode.getExamplesMenu());
          sketchMenu.remove(mode.getImportMenu());
          mode.removeToolbarRecentMenu();
        }
      });
```

Full code: http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=LfGSIGX0O67nvFyO4lEKQDA5zxE&cid=80HR_JtEBgg&s=How%20to%20alternate%20between%20printing%20in%20console%20and%20printing%20in%20a%20text%20file&pp=0&fl=Java&ff=1&filterChecked=true&fp=1237&mp,=1&ml=0&me=1&md=1&projSelected=true#L0